# Curl w3c linkckecker

Tags: curl, hyperlink

I would like to use w3c link checker from commandline
i've tried

```
curl http://validator.w3.org/checklink?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.paginasargentina.info%2F&summary=on&hide_redirects=on&hide_type=all&recursive=on&depth=&cookie=set&check=Check >> check.html
```

need it to Check linked documents recursively

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap url with quotations marks and that should work (now there are problems because of ampersand - it makes your curl command run in background).

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to use the public instance of the link checker. The W3C provide [a locally installable version](http://validator.w3.org/docs/checklink#install) (which includes [a command line utility](https://metacpan.org/module/checklink)).

It depends on Perl, which [is a free download](http://www.perl.org/get.html).